# Html/CSS: Scrolling background

Tags: css, background

I want the background of my html document to stay in the upper left corner of the page, allowing the user to see only parts of it when he scrolls through the page.

The code I use is:

```
<body style="background-image: url(background.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-attachment:scroll;

            width:1400px;
            height:2000px;">
```

This works how it should in the browsers. In the software I'm using though: MS Expression Web 4, the image moves with the window horizontally! Vertically it doesn't.

So now is the failure in my code (which Chrome happens to interpret how I want it), or is it a bug in Expression Web 4?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would test it in other browsers first, but it sound to me like a bug in expression web 4.  Your code looks right, but be sure it works on all major browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!
It seems to work in all browsers.. but I'd like to have it properly in the software too. Are there any other possibilities to make the background scrolling than with that atribute?

Comment: Glad I could help.  Since the scrolling background seems to be a glitch in expression web 4, you might google your problem and see if there is a patch fix it. I don't use expression web 4, so I wouldn't know. But whatever you do, don't change your code just so it'll work in expression. It will mess up your site in a real browser.

Comment: 8/19/2019 and there are still issues in Expression Web 4 with background scrolling correctly. When I Googled it this question is the first result.